# Error in Sending Email through VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim composeitem As Outlook.MailItem

Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
composeitem = myOlApp.CreateItem(0)
With composeitem
    .To = "abc.xyz@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "ABC meeting"
    .Body = "Meeting at 5"
    .Send   
    .Display
End With
```

The **error** VBA is throwing is that **" Object Variable or With block Variable not Set"**  I have marked all the required references and get error on the **CreateItem(0)** line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `OutApp` and `myOlApp`?

Comment: I may be wrong but don't you need to use the `Set` with the line on which you are getting the error?

Comment: @DavidZemens I corrected that, but that's not the reason for the error. I forgot to edit when I posted but the error still remains. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks!. I totally made a fool of myself not using the Set for the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a **set** in your **CreateItem(0)** line. Change that line to the following:

```
Set composeitem = myOlApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Additionally, your **.Display** will throw an error because the email message is deleted after you run the **.Send** command. I would suggest moving the lines around to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

`composeitem` is an object, so you need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning to it.

I also note you have redundantly included two object variables for the Outlook Application.  Fix it:

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim composeitem As Outlook.MailItem

'  This isn't needed: --> Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set composeitem = myOlApp.CreateItem(0)
With composeitem
    .To = "abc.xyz@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "ABC meeting"
    .Body = "Meeting at 5"
    .Send   
    '.Display  you can't display a message that's already been sent
End With
```